# React display localized version of error message

Tags: json, reactjs, api, error-handling, localization

I'm doing an FrontEnd using React and I'm using L10n for localization. It works well to display static text ex:

```
<input {...input} type="password" placeholder={strings.passwordPlaceholder} className="my-2 rounded-full" />
```

strings.passwordPlaceholder will check the l10n files and display the good strings that correspond to the chosen language.

The problem I have is when I try to display an error message coming back from the API. In the following example, I would like to display Wrong Password (Mot de Passe incorrect in french) or User is Locked Out (Utilisateur verrouillé in french) depending on the return from the API. The JSON return is:

```
{"message":"wrongPassword"}
```

or

```
{"message":"userLockedOut"}
```

My command line to display the error is:

```
{error && <span className="text-numerid-gray italic">{error.message}</span>}
```

That displays only wrongPassword or userLockedOut without calling the l10n files. What should I call instead of {error­.message} and how should I configure the l10n files to be able to get the return, call the l10n file and display the good text?

Thank you

Comment: I went further by doing this line
```
{error && <span className="text-numerid-gray italic">{strings.[error.message]}</span>}  
```
It works in French but not in English and I have a Identifier Expected error.

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me, is to store an object with the errors in the following fashion on the front end:

```
{
    wrong_password: {
        english: 'Wrong password',
        french: 'Mauvais mot de passe'
    },
    email_already_in_use: {
        english: 'Email already in use',
        french: 'Email déjà utilisé'
    },
}
```

This way, you can send any error message from your API and display it on the front end in the language you want.

For example, your API will send a response like this:

```
{
    error: 'wrong_password'
}
```

and then you can get the text you need in the following fashion:

```
import errorList from './path/to/your/errors/file';

const err = errorList[wrong_password][userLanguage];

console.log(err);

// output:
// english: Wrong password
// french: Mauvais mot de passe
```

In case the errors are categorized by language, you should do the following:

```
import frenchErrors from './path/to/french/errors';
import englishErrors from './path/to/english/errors';

function getError(lang, err) {
    let errList = englishErrors;
    if (lang === 'french') {
        errList = frenchErrors;
    }
    
    return errList[err];
}

const text = getError(userLanguage, err);

console.log(text);

// and you get the respective outcome
```

Comment: The way it's setup right now, I have a en.js and fr.js with english and French text. I would like to incorporate the error messages in these files.

Comment: I've posted the solutions you require.

Comment: Sorry I was tired yesterday. I get it now. However, how can I handle it if the same API can return another error message (ex. User_Locked_Out). Can I put the error message in a variable and call the variable to display the localized error message?

Comment: You should maintain a list of all the errors your API can send back. Also, make sure you use a function when getting a translated error, to avoid app crashes in case you make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the problem is to put the change the Error line in the view like this:

```
{error && <span className="text-numerid-gray italic">{strings[error.message]}</span>}
```

I just had to put the entries in both en.js and fr.js for the API return messages and everything worked.